# How can I make my CSR 4.0 work?

Tags: 20.04, kernel, bluetooth

I bought a CSR 4.0 bluetooth toogle hopping to use for music and stuff. I have already tried a plug n' play BT toogle but I can't remember its brand or model (it was white though). It worked for 4.0 devices but not for my 5.0 headphone for instance.

When I did the same thing for this "plug n' play" usb toogle it didn't work. After search the web and countless forums I come here again asking for help. Here is a quick list of thinks I tried and some details of the issue:

1. First I installed the bluez and blueman packages (through synaptic) both in dev versions as well. When I open it and try to pair with my phone, [it keeps searching endlessly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SjrL.png).
2. Also while blueman tries to search, the [bluetooth system tool does as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIJrz.png).
3. However, after installing the packages, [my desktop is recognizable by my phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzIPl.jpg). But when I try to pair them: [an error mensage apears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKHUr.jpg).

That was pretty much what I did to solve it. The rest was me trying to diagnose the problem. It follows:

```
$ dmesg | grep Bluetooth
[   26.575777] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   26.575801] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   26.575806] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   26.575809] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   26.575812] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   27.131101] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Unbranded CSR clone detected; adding workarounds...
[   50.842293] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   50.842294] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   50.842302] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[  108.698627] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  108.698636] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  108.698643] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  275.396684] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c3a tx timeout

...

[  847.972771] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0401 tx timeout
[ 1135.777423] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c14 tx timeout
[ 1596.128411] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Unbranded CSR clone detected; adding workarounds...
[ 1614.944973] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0401 tx timeout

...

[ 8563.066095] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0401 tx timeout
[ 9612.606636] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Unbranded CSR clone detected; adding workarounds...
[ 9632.069367] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0401 tx timeout
[ 9644.069487] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0401 tx timeout
[ 9656.073641] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0401 tx timeout
[ 9668.069734] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0401 tx timeout
[ 9680.069856] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0401 tx timeout
[ 9692.069981] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0401 tx timeout
[ 9704.074094] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0401 tx timeout
[ 9716.070247] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0401 tx timeout
[ 9728.070347] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0401 tx timeout
[ 9740.070431] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0401 tx timeout
```

And:

```
    $ lsusb | grep Cambridge
    Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
$ hciconfig
 hci0:  Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:1A:7D:DA:71:10  ACL MTU: 640:4  SCO MTU: 64:8
    UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 
    RX bytes:778 acl:0 sco:0 events:61 errors:0
    TX bytes:4789 acl:0 sco:0 commands:591 errors:540
```

Finally I saw that tip in one askubuntu topic and tried my own. The result:

```
$ sudo hcidump
HCI sniffer - Bluetooth packet analyzer ver 5.53
device: hci0 snap_len: 1500 filter: 0xffffffffffffffff
< HCI Command: Inquiry (0x01|0x0001) plen 5
    lap 0x9e8b33 len 8 num 0
< HCI Command: Reset (0x03|0x0003) plen 0
```

As a result of the code from another terminal tab

```
$ sudo hciconfig hci0 down
$ sudo hciconfig hci0 up
Can't init device hci0: Connection timed out (110)
```

So long I've seen, `$ sudo hciconfig hci0 reset` also works. Then the [bluetooth system manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oS94k.png) and [gnome control panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wK82v.png) behave like this and I have to remove and insert the device to be connected again.

Finally, I read that this could happen as the kernel were updated from Ubuntu 16 to 20. Mine is **5.8.0-43-generic**, but people complain about this problem since 5.4. I'm not sure if installing an old kernel would solve it once I know almost nothing about it.

Any help is welcome ;)

Comment: Are you sure the Bluetooth dongle you are using supports Bluetooth 5?

Comment: It doesn't. The point is it is a 4.0 BT dongle and it doesn't recognize even my mobile phone (which works for 4.0 connection once I've done it before). Also the white dongle I mentioned was a 4.0 and connected poorly (bad sound) with a 5.0 headphone. I thought this could do the same.

Comment: Please confirm your OS & release, as you mention Ubuntu 20 & the 5.8 kernel which is from Ubuntu 20.10; are you using Ubuntu 20.10 as that is EOL?  You've tagged 20.04 which has 5.4 as the GA kernel stack & 5.15 as the HWE kernel; 5.8 being from a now EOL release.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/06/18/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-22-2021/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with my CBR 4 usb dongle that I bought recently from a local pc shop, but occasionally mine works great.
The last time I was able to make it work( a few minutes ago), I unplugged the dongle and stopped bluetooth.service, waited 1 minute, started bluetooth.service, plugged in the dongle and it worked again immediately.. This is after another episode of starting/stopping/restarting bluetooth.service, unplugging/replugging dongle, lsusbs, and hciconfig hci0 ups/downs/resets. sometimes it works on reboot. it's a real pain in my neck. I am considering asking for a refund and going with another 13 dollar Sabrent dongle from amazon like my last one which works flawlessly.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1238676)

Comment: ah, yes I agree, I have no solution. thank you.